# Add string to list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to get a list:

```
'abc0'
'abc1'
'abc2'
...
'abc9'
```

the command `range(10)` returns a list of numbers from 0 to 9, but how do I add the string `'abc'` to every element in the list?

Comment: You asked for a list, but you might be better off with a generator expression, at least if your range can grow beyond just 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> ['abc' + str(i) for i in range(10)]

['abc0', 'abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4', 'abc5', 'abc6', 'abc7', 'abc8', 'abc9']
```